# How to connect dots and segments on image to form continuous curve?

Tags: image-processing

For example, I have images like

[image]

or

[image]

How to connect those segments to form a continuous lines are immediately obvious to the human eye. But how to do it automatically with Mathematica?

Comment: Are all your curves are [Lissajous curves](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve#/media/File%3ALissajous_relaciones.png)?

Comment: @I.M. Yeah, for the current task. It is. But I would like to have a general solution.

Answer (score 6):

One approach is to take all the white points, thin, find the shortest path, and then reconnect. For example:

```
im = Binarize[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kazl.png"]]
tour = FindShortestTour[pos = Position[ImageData[Thinning[im]], 1]];
ImageRotate[ColorNegate[Image[Graphics[Line[pos[[Last[tour]]]]]]], 90 Degree]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you bill s. But this code is not reliable. What I got using your code is different from yours. See https://postimg.cc/HcnvYp3S

Comment: I think a better approach would take account of the directions of line segments

Comment: The picture was generated using the above code. And of course, there are always different/better ways of accomplishing anything. Perhaps you would care to share your directional lines code?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to do those directional lines things : ) I am just thinking maybe that will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Following Bill's idea:

```
im = LocalAdaptiveBinarize[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kazl.png"], 100, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
tour = FindShortestTour[pos = Position[ImageData[Thinning[im, Infinity, 0.9, Method -> "MedialAxis"]], 1]];
ImageRotate[ColorNegate[Image[Graphics[BSplineCurve[pos[[Last[tour]]], SplineDegree -> 100]]]], 90 Degree]
```

[image]